# Retrieve vertex colors in 2.8

Tags: vertex-colors

2.79 allowed you to set shading to flat, which would render the vertex color 1:1 on screen (assuming the entire normal had been solidly colored and noting else is being set to diffuse, of course excluding vertex color interpolation). This allowed you to retrieve the exact color assigned to any vertex on the normal. It wasn't ideal, but it worked if needed.

I'm still fumbling around with 2.8. So far it seems actual "flat" shading renders desaturated in Vertex Paint, so this method is gone - every rendering mode and its subsequent options apply some sort of saturation, shading, light dependency, or cubemap. It doesn't introduce the option to view colors per selection (still), doesn't offer alpha (still), and doesn't even offer color space selection (still).

Are either of the following even possible in 2.8?

1. just plainly view vertex colors on a mesh without any superfluous shading, rendering, or antialising from edges, without the need for additional light set up and material building
2. simply, plainly, retrieve color values as stored per normal

Really sad that it's still lacking so much functionality in vertex colors, it should *at least* have some option to view vertex colors plainly, regardless of angle or light, or at least view color values per selection. Vertex colors are a valuable asset in the world of rendering as it pertains to potential for blending, displacement, etc, but these features are still missing.

I'm already having to switch between color spaces at runtime in my rendering software. And I've had to use a variety of other works around to implement alpha and simply preview colors plainly.

How do you retrieve simple, plain, vertex color values in Blender 2.8? Is such a thing built in yet, or do you have to access it through Python or some other means?